# UIButton selected text not showing for selected state

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

All,

I have a UI element that contains a button. I set the text on the button, and simultaneously, the selected state. See below:

```
- (void)setText:(NSString *)text {
    self.inputButton.selected = text != nil; // select the buttons if the text is not nil
    self.cancelButton.selected = text != nil;

    [self.inputButton setTitle:text forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [self.inputButton setTitle:text forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
}
```

this is working properly when filled out in the view controller.

However, when I passed the text in from the previous view controller, the selected state text doesn't display. The `cancelButton` selected state works properly, and the `inputButton` state is supposedly selected, however, selected state text isn't displaying.

I don't know if it's because the button isn't redrawing or something? I've tried all the [self layoutIfNeed] and [self setNeedsDisplay] with no luck. Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: Are you positive that `text` is not `nil` when passed from the previous view controller?

Comment: yes. definitely not nil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the issue. I was using both the selected and highlighted states. For some funky reason, that was creating a situation where the button state could be 5. I resolved the problem by not addressing the `UIControlStateHighlighted` in any way.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check adding following line of code.

```
- (void)setText:(NSString *)text {
    self.inputButton.selected = text != nil; // select the buttons if the text is not nil
    self.cancelButton.selected = text != nil;

    [self.inputButton setTitle:text forState:UIControlStateSelected];
//Start:Added line of Code
    [self.inputButton setTitle:text forState:UIControlStateNormal];
//End:
    [self.inputButton setTitle:text forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
}
```

Thanks & Regards,

Amit

Comment: I don't want to change the text for the UIControlStateNormal though. I have different text that displays for that state

Comment: Hi, Can you share the piece of code where you have set the text for Normal state. Regards, Amit